# gaierror [Errno 8] when send_mail with Django python and gmail

Tags: python, django, gmail

I'm new with Django an Python.
I was following this tutorial ["Try Django 16"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51mmqf5a0Ss)
I don't get it work. I added `fail_silent=false` to get the error.

```
[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Is there anyone who can help me find this problem?

```
gaierror at /thank-you/
[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/thank-you/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: gaierror
Exception Value:    
[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Exception Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py in create_connection, line 553
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['/Users/andremensink/Desktop/skillshare/src',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 28 Jun 2014 13:23:10 +0000




Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/thank-you/

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'south',
 'signups')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/andremensink/Desktop/skillshare/src/signups/views.py" in thankyou
  40.         send_mail(subject,message,from_email,to_list,fail_silently=False)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py" in send_mail
  50.                         connection=connection).send()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  274.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
  87.             new_conn_created = self.open()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in open
  48.                                            local_hostname=DNS_NAME.get_fqdn())
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py" in __init__
  250.             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py" in connect
  310.         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py" in _get_socket
  285.         return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py" in create_connection
  553.     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):

Exception Type: gaierror at /thank-you/
Exception Value: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

The code in python is:

```
#--django stuff
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail #EmailMessage#send_mail
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect

    subject = 'This is the subject'
    message = 'Welcome to the list and enjoy your product.\n This is the message.'
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    to_list = [save_it.email,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
    send_mail(subject,message,from_email,to_list,fail_silently=False)
```

in the settings is defined:

```
#for gmail or google apps
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smpt.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

Comment: That screenshot appears to relate to a competent different problem. And you should paste the text of the error rather than the image, anyway.

Comment: The text is placed in stead of the screenshots. What kind of problem could it be than?

Comment: where is your "send email" code? what are the settings? the error sounds like it wants a "FROM" email or machine name, but didn't get it.

Comment: I added the code where the mailing is handled. I think the FROM email should be good but I can't find anything about the machine name. If I search for the hostname or computername, they are both the same.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smpt.gmail.com'
```

What is smpt?

```
should be EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol